# Is there a concept of a build script dependency?

Tags: sbt

In Gradle, there is a concept of a [`buildscript` dependency](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html), in that you can add an external dependency that the build script depends on to run. This is similar to SBT's plugins, except way more lightweight. With Gradle, I can add `X` as a dependency and then write Groovy code using the contents of `X`.  I need to use an external Java library inside of my build script and the mechanisms to do this are far from obvious to me in SBT.

With SBT, the closest thing I've found in the documentation is `addSbtPlugin`, which works great if there is an `X` SBT plugin, but it isn't in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Sbt builds are recursive, you can add a project/build.sbt file then add libraryDependency += ... to it.